# While reading and rewriting XML in Java, is there a systematic way of preserving the processing instruction?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, dom4j

I want to update the XML but preserve the original processing instruction, most of the time it's just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

However I can't find a way to extract the line from com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.JAXPSAXParser(and other XML reader) or how to automatically carry it to the write. Is there any other way than manually read the line, keep it then write it first before flushing the new XML ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code which reads the old XML content and write the new XML content.

Answer (score 2):

It's proper name is an XML declaration; it looks like a processing instruction but technically it isn't one.

Parsing invariably involves decoding the file (that is, converting the octets into characters); once that has been done, the theory goes, the application doesn't need to know how they were originally encoded. Similarly, when serializing the file, the application has to tell the serializer what encoding to use, and the serializer then takes responsibility for writing an XML declaration that reflects that encoding.

Allowing the application control over the XML declaration would break proper architectural layering, and would create the possibility of writing an XML declaration that is wrong. This bit of the content belongs to the parser layer, not to the application layer.

Of course in practice it's possible to get an XML declaration that doesn't match the actual encoding anyway, because there's nothing to stop you writing an XML declaration using software that knows nothing about XML. People do that, and they create broken content, and then they ask us on StackOverflow how to fix it. I'm not going to encourage you down that route.